# How to resize a Dialog before calling its show method?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialog

I have a dialog with an `EditText` on it, and it's with `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Before I call the show method, I set some text on it with `setText("Some string")`.

And when the `show()` method is called, the dialog isn't resized, and the EditText don't appear.

Is there a way to resize it before call `show()`.

Here is the code:

```
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_supply_history);

            EditText txtStartDate = dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtStartDate);
            txtStartDate.setText(sdf.format(startDate.getTime()));
            EditText txtFinalDate = dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtFinalDate);
            txtFinalDate.setText(sdf.format(finalDate.getTime()));

            dialog.show();
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblStartDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/lblStartDate"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/txtStartDate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgStartDate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgStartDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtStartDate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtStartDate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lblStartDate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtStartDate"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_today" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtStartDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="date"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgStartDate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblFinalDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="@string/lblFinalDate"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/txtFinalDate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFinalDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtFinalDate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtFinalDate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imgStartDate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtFinalDate"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_today" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtFinalDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="date"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgFinalDate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtStartDate" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: No codes, no truth.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-call your method that shows your dialog with the new layout

Comment: There isn't a new layout... Just the EditText now with be wider...
And I call dialog.show() after setting the text

Comment: Does your layout contains both editexts?? The layout you inflate I mean

Comment: Yeap... I added the layout file.

Comment: I think you should use an alertDialog instead of a dialog. It's easy to implement and use and I think that problem will be solved

Comment: Android recomends to use AlertDialog instead of Dialog. The Dialog class y the base for AlertDialog and others.

Answer (score 0):

If your dialog was an activity using another Dialog themes, you can try setting this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Alternatively, you can refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setSoftInputMode(int)) and use:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```